# Jquery div hiding when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have an image and when I hover over it the options appear below it. When i move down to the options they hide. I have set the slideUp not to happen until the user moves away from the parent div

```
$('.file-options').hide();
$('.file a img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.file').find('.file-options').slideDown();
});
$('.file a img').closest('.file').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('.file-options').slideUp();
});

<div class="document">
  <div class="file">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.dermalog.com/images/pdf-icon.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="file-options showhouse-text">
        <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" class="show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete File">D</a>
        <a href="#" class="show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit File">E</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5vAFh/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mouseout` event from the `<img>` is bubbling up to the `.file` element, and therefore triggering your code to hide the `<div>`. Use the `mouseleave` event (which doesn't react to events bubbling) instead:

```
$('.file a img').closest('.file').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.file-options').slideUp();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vAFh/4/)

Comment: `$('.file').mouseleave()` is enough isn't it ?

Comment: why not `$('.file:has(a img')).mouseleave`

Comment: How come the mouseout was doing it wrong and mouseleave was right?

Comment: @mikakun Probably, though they may have other `.file` elements that they don't want to bind this functionality too. The selector works for what they want, even if there are potentially better alternatives, so I didn't change them.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough [This page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseenter) should explain it; essentially they don't react to event bubbling (unlike mouseout) so that event originating from the `<img>` won't result in the event handler bound to `.file` firing. It's not a standard event (IE only), so it's simulated by jQuery for the other browsers.

Comment: Ah right, thanks very much. What would be a potentially better alternative? Is it easier to do or less code?

Comment: @PierceMcGeough The only reason to choose another selector is performance, and only if you're actually having issues with the execution speed of your code. In this case it seems like it would be premature optimisation, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thats great, I can actually just use .file because they all will hide. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**or** you could do this: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/USBRy/

check for `if(!$(this).is(':hover')) {`

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
$('.file-options').hide();

$('.file a img').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).closest('.file').find('.file-options').slideDown();
});

$('.file a img').closest('.file').mouseout(function (e) {
    if(!$(this).is(':hover')) {
        $(this).find('.file-options').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.. Try this:

```
$('.file-options').hide();

$('.file').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('.file-options').slideDown();
});

$('.file').mouseout(function(e){
    if($(e.toElement).parents('.file').length < 1) {
       $(this).find('.file-options').slideUp();
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vAFh/12/